# Linear Interpolation - No external libraries except Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working through a quiz where you have to implement some machine learning concepts from scratch. One question asks to implement linear interpolation in python without any external libraries besides numpy. The question states:

Q: Given the input data of points [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 8), (7, -1)], fit a line of the form Y = A * X + B using gradient descent. Provide the implementation of your algorithm in the function provided using no external libraries, except for numpy. The evaluate linear regression fit on the provided point.

```
def linear_interpolate_point(data, x):
    """
    Fit a line to the provided data and then evaluate on the provided test point.
    :param data: Collection of points to fit provided as a list of tuples
    :param x: Point to interpolate using your fit line
    :return: The output of your point on the interpolated line
    """
    # fill in function below
```

I've tried a few different concepts but seem to be stumped on what the question is asking.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `np.interp` [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html]

Comment: `np.interp` might be bordering on cheating.  Sounds like  they want you  Linear interpolation is something we did in school before computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear regression can be formalized as follows: `f(x) = x*m + b`, where `b` is a bias weigth and `m` is a weigth that is multiplied with the input. What gradient descent does is to optimize the `m` and `b` based on your data. So let's set up an initial model based on your data.

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (8, 8), (7, -1)])
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 0]
m = 0
b = 0
```

With the initial model we can run a several optimization steps with gradient descent to optimize the weights. Gradient descent basically just computes in which direction to change the weights `b` and `m`. We further specify how much iterations we allow for optimization (`max_iterations`) and how much we move in the direction of the gradient (`eta`).

```py
def gradient_descent(x, y, m, b, eta, max_iterations):
    n = x.shape[0]
    for iteration in range(max_iterations):
        y_hat = x * m + b
        error = y - y_hat
        # Compute gradient for m and b
        gradient_m = (-2/n) * x.dot(error)
        gradient_b = (-2/n) * sum(error)
        # Update weights
        m = m - eta*gradient_m
        b = b - eta*gradient_b
    
    return m, b

m, b = gradient_descent(x, y, m, b, 1e-2, 1000)
```

Now plotting the data and the model with optimized weights.

```
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(np.linspace(1, 8, 100), np.linspace(1, 8, 100) * m + b )
plt.show()
```

[image]

For a complete explanation how gradient descent works probably some blog posts are better than stackoverflow, e.g. [Gradient Descent](https://towardsdatascience.com/linear-regression-using-gradient-descent-97a6c8700931).